# Where is there a list of Server Variables or <allowedServerVariables>?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, url-rewriting

I want to know if there is a place that lists my server variables.

I'm using Rewrite Url and I'm curious what I could effect.

I found this [blog article](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/viewing-all-server-variables-for-a-site) that lists the variables on a web page. I don't really want to add this to the site if there's another way.

I've also researched [Rewrite Url](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Allowed_Server_Variables_List) and all they say is:

> **ALLOWED SERVER VARIABLES LIST**
>
> Global rewrite rules can be used to set any request headers and server
>   variables, as well as overwrite any existing ones. Distributed rewrite
>   rules can only set/overwrite the request headers and server variables
>   that are defined in the allowed list for server variables
>   <allowedServerVariables>. If a distributed rewrite rule attempts to
>   set any server variable or an HTTP header that is not listed in the
>   <allowedServerVariables> collection a runtime error will be generated
>   by URL Rewrite Module. The <allowedServerVariables> collection by
>   default is stored in applicationHost.config file and can be modified
>   only by an IIS server administrator.

Where can I find a list of my server variables?

If I don't have server adminstrator access, is there a list of common server variables that I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By searching for a specific server variable I came across these two pages. This was pretty much what I was looking for.

[ASP Server Variables](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp) (W3Schools)

[IIS 6.0 Server Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (Microsoft)

Answer (score 5):

It is also worth noting that when you add a Condition in the IIS URL Rewrite feature, then start typing in the "Condition Input" box, a complete list of variables is shown...

[image]